# How to training/testing my custom model (net) in caffe?

Tags: model, neural-network, caffe

I just started using caffe and was amazed by its ease for training and testing models. I just wanted to train my own model( net) and keep using it.

For more explanations, I have a Specific multi layer model like as bellow picture. (My input data is breast-cancer data set.):
 [image: My specific multi layer model, Click it please]

(This model is not fully connected neural network, and some weights are omitted as you can see in picture.)

**My certain question is, how to implement this model in caffe?!**

Many thanks!!!! Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: you are looking for a *Locally connected* layer. I'm not sure if it was implemented yet. See [this thread](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/pull/3068) for example.

Comment: thanks  @Shai
but what is your idea for create this model ?!

Comment: look into "Slice" and "Concat" layers.

Comment: Thanks your attentions @Shai